# Need help with rearranging words

Tags: articles-definis

I have a task where I need to rearrange some french words to make meaningful sentences.

1. fait, sport, du, Jules
2. a, le, On, français, fois, de, cours, deux
3. de, ordinateur, noir, L’, l’, écran, est
4. vais, les, acheter, pour, je, fruits

These are my answers.

1. Jules fait du sport
2. On a de deux cours français le fois
3. L’de est ordinateur écran l'noir
4. je les pour acheter vais fruits

Is my answer correct, if not please tell the correct answer with explaination

Comment: My french teacher always told me : SUJET VERBE COMPLEMENT !! haha let me see if I can help

Comment: Only the first one is correct

Comment: oh i am so bad at this :( but i am trying

Comment: No trouble at least you tried we're both newbie here ^^

Comment: For the third answer, how did you arrive at "L’de" and "l'noir"?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is homework and the OP needs to do it her/himself.

Answer (score 3):

So :

1. Jules fait du sport // Jules is working out
2. On a deux fois le cours de français // We have twice the french lecture
3. L'ecran de l'ordinateur est noir. // The screen is black ,
4. Je vais pour acheter les fruits ?

The thing is that you translated word by word (English > French) and it doesn't work every time